# Use module scripts in web worker

Tags: web-worker, es6-modules

Web worker scripts are loaded when a `Worker` is instantiated but how can I use a script that is a module so I don't get an error? (assume the browser supports modules).

```
const worker = new Worker('my-worker.js')
```

In `my-worker.js`

```
import {foo} from 'foo.js'
console.log(foo)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web Workers - How To Import Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118600/web-workers-how-to-import-modules)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`type` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker#Parameters):

```
const worker = new Worker('my-worker.js', {type:"module"});
```

- type: A [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) specifying the type of worker to create. The value can be `classic` or `module`. If not specified, the default used is `classic`.

Comment: Thanks, I had figured it out already but forgot I had this opened question.