# Use ESM in a service worker file (import/export)

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I am trying to use a service worker file which is also an ESM module.

The `register` method has an extra argument accepting an `options` object which has a `type` field whose valid values seem to be `classic` and `module`, but when I use:

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.register('worker.js', { type: 'module' });
// `worker.mjs` doesn't work either
// The file exists in both cases!
```

I get an unspecified `DOMException` with no message in Chrome.

I figured what the valid values for `type` were by reading the spec, specifically this:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#workertype

It seems to me like my code is valid.

As a sanity check, I also tried to explicity set `type` to `classic` and the service worker registration then goes through fine. If I set it to an invalid value, I get a `TypeError` telling me so, so it's not like the browser is not yet aware of `type: module`. It is treated as a special case, it just throws a `DOMException` with no message.

Am I using the `type` field correctly? Is it still too early and it is not supported in browsers?

Comment: `.mjs` is a Node.js thing, not an ESM thing outside Node.js. (And Node.js now has `type`. Hopefully `.mjs` will die a death...)

Comment: What version of Chrome? Do the contents of your service worker script make any difference?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118600

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is dumb! Chrome will print just `DOMException` into the console (not even expansible) when logging the error object and `Object.keys` on that object instance returns `[]`, but when I specifically print `e.message` the culprit is revealed:

> type 'module' in RegistrationOptions is not implemented yet.See https://crbug.com/824647 for details.

Not amused by Chrome.

Comment: That link now states that "Yes, this is available in Chrome 91" which was released on May 25th, 2021.

Answer (score 2):

On browsers, bare names can't be used to identify modules unless you also have a [module map](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#module-map) (aka [import map](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps), this link has much more info) that maps the bare name to a module.

If `worker.js` is in the same location as the page loading it, then:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('./worker.js', { type: 'module' });
// -------------------------------^^
```

Or of course, add a module map.

Comment: Unfortunately this is just not supported and the error message is obscured beyond belief. Just figured it out after posting the question, see my answer.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer - Yeah, just saw that. When it *is* supported, I suspect you'll need to do the above, though. :-)

Comment: I will keep that in mind. With classic (the default) registrations, passing `worker.js` (no `./`) works just fine for me though. The browser is able to resolve the relative URL correctly.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer - Right, the requirement for a path or a map is specifically related to modules. For instance, for a non-worker, `<script src="foo.js"></script>` works; but without a map, `<script type="module" src="foo.js"></script>` does not, it has to be `<script type="module" src="./foo.js"></script>`.