# How Can a URL.createObjectUrl() Be a Module?

Tags: javascript, blob, web-worker, es6-modules

I've been using Web Workers for a while, but only now have I found the need to import a module into them. Upon attempting this, I was somewhat shocked to find that this is not yet possible in Firefox Dev 76. Having reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53877575) solution to the problem, I am somewhat at a loss. Here's what I'm doing:

I have a worker that needs to import a NodeJS module that works in the browser. This worker is generated from a given string of code. So, inside the generated worker, I'm running this:

```
//worker
let { foo } = importScripts("http://localhost:3000/some-blob-url");
```

Which imports anything else code successfully. I'm also, upon detecting an import in the given code string, running this code to generate another URL with the import code that exports the part of the module I want.

```
let blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([importingCode], { type: 'application/javascript' }));
```

Where `importingCode` is:

```
import { foo } from 'module';
export { foo };
```

However, upon importing the Blob URL in `worker.js`, I am told that imports can only occur at the top-level of a module, implying that this created Blob is not a module (importingCode).

How would I initialise `createObjectURL`, given a Blob of code, to be a module that supports imports. I am aware that the answer I linked to uses Webpack `require` statements, but I would like to avoid Webpack here. Is this possible to do?

Sorry if my question is vague, please tell me and I'm happy to clarify.

Comment: They don't even allow dynamic imports... Will be hard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118600/web-workers-how-to-import-modules

Comment: That's the question I linked to. One of the answers sparked a broader query, which I'm now asking about.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the native `import()` function inside your worker, which means this will only work in browsers that support workers with `{type: 'module'}`:

```js
const result = await import(blobURL)
```

where `blobURL` is the one you made in your example, and where `import` is the native function that ships with the browser.

Firefox finally supports worker modules as of June 2023: https://caniuse.com/?search=worker%20module