# Vue Workbox Webpack "cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: vue.js, webpack, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I'm trying to use workbox for the first time but I always get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

This is my src-sw.js

```
import {precacheAndRoute} from 'workbox-precaching';

precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
```

I couldn't find anything in the workbox documentation in regards to this problem. How do I handle this?

Comment: Its utterly confusing. @mishamosher says that you have to use importscripts, and yet all the examples on the workbox site use imports

Comment: @SimonH The examples on the workbox site suppose that you're using a transpiler/packer like webpack, Rollup, Parcel, or something else. This is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/get-started#installation). The error described by Binu suggests that no transpiler/bundler is being used, and such scenario is supported as described [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-bundlers#using_the_cdn_is_an_alternative_to_bundling) and [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-sw).

Comment: @SimonH Also, if indeed a transpiler/packer is in use, [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-bundlers) is more info about how to properly configure it.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the [Get Started](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/get-started) guide to start using Workbox.

Also, you can not use ES modules in ServiceWorkers (yet). Check here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45578811/1273042