# How to get transpiled code to run in a Worker (without Webpack)?

Tags: typescript, systemjs

I'm using a TypeScript project based on SystemJS, following this [example](https://blog.tekmi.nl/how-to-bundle-many-typescript-files-using-systemjs) whose code is at https://github.com/tekmi/blogging-typescript-with-bundlers/blob/master/systemjs/app.ts

I'm able to implement a simple Worker in TypeScript, e.g. from this [example](https://medium.com/@dmerlea/nail-web-workers-with-typescript-a2ef8c958c9b),

```js
// src/worker/simulator.ts
const scope = (self as unknown) as Worker

scope.addEventListener('message', event => {
    console.log(event.data)
    scope.postMessage('pong')
})
```

It runs fine in the SystemJS environment - I make sure that its code is transpiled *outside* of SystemJS, with a separate `tsconfig.json`, following the advice at this [blog](https://joshuatz.com/posts/2021/strongly-typed-service-workers/).

But as soon as I try something more complex in the Worker code, i.e., a class that imports/exports something, I hit snags with the code that runs. Depending on the transpiled format (`"module"` in the tsconfig), I get the following problems:

- `"module": "ESNext"` -> `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`
- `"module": "CommonJS"` -> `ReferenceError: exports is not defined`
- etc with System, AMD, there are errors relating to those contexts.

The transpiled code is loaded properly when invoked (I see it fine in the log for `lite-server`).

I invoke the worker inside the event code for a button on a web page:

```js
export function start(this: GlobalEventHandlers, ev: MouseEvent) {
    let worker = new Worker("../worker/simulator.js");
//...
```

My conclusion is there's some context missing in the transpiled worker code, but I can't figure out what it is. It's the first time I'm trying Workers in TypeScript.

Here's my `tsconfig.json` for the `src/worker` sub-project (this one is configured for CommonJS module transpilation):

```json
{
  "extends": "../generic-tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    // store the webworker transpiled files separately
    "outDir": "../../dist",
    "lib": [
      "ES6",
      "WebWorker"
    ],
  },
  "include": [
    "../worker/*",
    "../shared/*"
  ]
}
```

What is needed to allow a (complex) Worker to run in this configuration?

I want avoid Webpack if possible, mostly because I'm trying to understand what's happening.

Comment: You might find some clues at [Web Workers - How To Import Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118600/web-workers-how-to-import-modules) - are you creating your worker with the `type: module` option? I.e. `new Worker("worker.js", { type: "module" });`

Comment: @SethLutske your solution of `type: "module"` worked, at least for `"module": "ESNEXT"` - if you want to write it up as an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if you want to be able to use module syntax like `import` and `export` in a web worker, you need to define the worker with the `type: module` option, like this:

```js
new Worker("worker.js", { type: "module" });
```

This is discussed further in the question [Web Workers - How To Import Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118600/web-workers-how-to-import-modules)