# How to import functions to web worker?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, web-worker

I need to use two modules, originally in Typescript, inside my Javascript web worker. Webpack seems to be taking care about the compatibility problem. Now, to use the modules, I've tried using both `require` and `import`.

`require` gives me `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`, which, according to what I found, is because you can't use it on the browser, therefore `import` is the viable option. `import`, however, gives me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`, to which I found a possible solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118600/web-workers-how-to-import-modules), but while adding `{ type: "module" }` to the constructor does make the error go away, it also makes it so that my worker stops functioning.

In the file that calls `worker = new Worker(path, { type: "module" })`, I have a `worker.postMessage(msg)` call. In the worker, there is a

```
self.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
    doThingsWith(e)
    [...]
    self.postMessage(something)
}
```

event listener. From the moment I add `type: "module"`, anything inside the event listener does not work.